# If a person isn't sure he is Jewish, does he have to keep Mitzvot?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mitzvah, sin

Let's say that a person has a reason to think his mother might be Jewish (there is some evidence, but only a little), and it is likely that the person will never be able to know for sure. In such a case, does he sin if he is Jewish and does not keep Mitzvot?

Is there a precedent or a standard ruling as to what a person like this should do?  Should he convert?  Or do you say that maybe it does not matter because if a person is unaware they do not need to follow the law?

(I am not writing about myself even thought I was in such a situation, as I have already made a decision what to do next. It is because I am curious about my family members.)

The question is **not about conversion**, it is about being unsure about whether one is a Jew and living like a gentile and if that is wrong.

Comment: And what's more, some mitzvos — like keeping Shabbos — are forbidden to a non-Jew, so there's no way to be machmir. (Though there is that story (I don't remember where) where the doubtful non-Jew did no melachah except wearing tzitzis which are useless to a non-Jew and therefore only considered carrying when worn by the non-Jew.)

Comment: @ba Genius idea!

Comment: @ba: I've heard that with regards to Avraham Avinu (who we are told kept the whole Torah). There is a disagreement if he had the status of a Ben Noach or a Jew. The question is then, what did he do about Shabbat. If he was not Jewish, he could not keep Shabbat, if he was Jewish, he couldn't break Shabbat. There are actually several answer given to this question by different rabbis over the years. One of them was that he wore tzitzit. - it's been a while, but I'm pretty sure i heard it here: http://insidechassidus.org/inside-talmud/131-selected-topics/833-did-avrohom-avinu-keep-shabbos.html

Comment: @Menachem I don't see the problem — whether Avraham was a Jew or non-Jew, he certainly knew which he was (he had nevuah), even if later rabbis didn't. Therefore, he could have either kept or not kept Shabbos (the Torah seems to not specify one or the other)

Comment: I think there will be more questions like this as people in countries struck by the Shoah and totalitarism start to dig into their ancestral origins. I think there should be a ruling on this matter by a respectful posek (am I not confusing it?) because the people will ask this question. In Eastern Europe one could be openly Jewish or have a life. It is difficult to get information even from family members who would rather not say, because for so long being Jewish was like a crime. I can see my ancestral surnames on ghetto lists and wonder...

Comment: I'm getting stuck on what the Original Poster means by "not aware." If the person has no idea at all that they might actually be Jewish, then I would assume that they are in the category of not obeying the mitzvot by accident, shogeg, or even by compulsion, oness. In the time of the Beit haMikdash, they would have to bring a korban when they found out that they were really Jewish. But I'm not completely sure this is the situation the poster is asking about. This poster seems to imply that the people do suspect, which means they do have some awareness, and that's a very different question.

Comment: @Shemmy: In this particular case there is genetic evidence as the mother has many Jewish cousins, and, there is little written evidence on the paternal side of the mother. Maternal side of the mother is very unclear, no genealogical evidence so far, but genetic testing cannot yet prove or disprove if the line is Jewish, there is a tiny bit of genetic evidence that it is possible. The bottom line is that the Jewish ancestry of the mother is only more likely to be on the paternal line, it could be maternal line, but those who could tell more are dead now.

Comment: @Shemmy: also in the question it is mentioned there is evidence but little, meaning there is a reason to think mother might be Jewish. So it is explicitly written in the question. Down to the details: mother's X chromosome has Jewish X chromosome matches not longer than several generations ago. X chromosome has a specific pattern of inheritance which makes it much more likely for maternal lines to carry the bulk of genes to the offspring because I and all men only have X from the mother.

Comment: Well, the question and title are worded strangely. How can a person who doesn't know he is Jewish be required to keep laws he doesn't know apply to him (or may not even know exist)? The title is also different from the body. The body suggests the person suspects he may be Jewish. I'm going to edit this to make them match and to try to improve the question. Feel free to revert if you think my changes don't match your intent.

Comment: @ba: see about halfway through this http://rchaimqoton.blogspot.com.au/2006/07/resting-on-seventh-day.html - The answer with the Tzitzit is brought by the Chatam Sofer.

Comment: @SethJ: it can always be improved, so thank you. The question however still remains a great dilemma, for myself at least.

Comment: I'm not aware of standard rabbinical ruling on this issue, but from a commonsense perspective, one would not be obligated in the mitzvot simply because one knows there is a slight possibility that one might be Jewish. I would say that it is best to inform these people that they may be Jewish, or at least have some Jewish ancestors. If they are in fact Jewish or are meant to convert, their neshama will be aroused to do research into Judaism (as well as into their genealogy) and eventually to convert ("l'chumra" or not, depending on the level of certainty).

Comment: The recently-published book Bnei Avraham Avuvecha: Gerim in Chassidic Thought by Dov ben Avraham contains some interesting material about gerim descended from Jews. This may be of interest to those of uncertain Jewish status.

Comment: A different solution to the shabbes problem is that for a gentile, the day begins and ends at midnight: doing melacha motzoei shabbes!

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in Kesubos 15b discusses the status of a child found in the street.  Depending on the population demographics of the city, there are different halachos:

> אם רוב <עובדי כוכבים> {גוים} <עובד כוכבים> {גוי} אמר שמואל ולפקח עליו את הגל אינו כן אם רוב <עובדי כוכבים> {גוים} <עובד כוכבים> {גוי} למאי הלכתא אמר רב פפא להאכילו נבילות אם רוב ישראל ישראל למאי הלכתא אמר רב פפא להחזיר לו אבידה מחצה על מחצה ישראל למאי הלכתא אמר ריש לקיש לנזקין

Meaning (of the pertinent first line):  If it is majority non-Jews, we do not dismiss the possibility that he is a Jew when it comes to saving his life on Shabbos.  However, we will feed him non-kosher meat (i.e. we allow him and can even enable him to violate Jewish mitzvos).

If there is a non-negligible but weak indication that a person is Jewish, they still are not obligated to keep the commandments.

Answer (score 1):

If a person is Jewish, he or she is obligated to follow halacha. If a person is not Jewish, he or she is obligated to follow the Noahide laws, and forbidden from doing certain things, such as marrying a Jew, wearing tefillin, or observing Shabbos completely.

For these reasons, it seems clear that a person unsure if he or she is Jewish is obligated to investigate as much as possible to determine whether the person is Jewish. For example, the person should amass whatever family records and genealogical information is available, even if one has to pay for a genealogical service to do this.

If the resulting information still suggests that the person might be Jewish, the person should approach an Orthodox rabbi, or an Orthodox beis din, and ask whether this is good enough evidence for the person's Jewishness.

If the information is not enough to prove the person is Jewish, or it proves the person isn't Jewish, and the person desires to join the Jewish people and become an observant Jew, then the person should pursue Orthodox conversion. If the information points strongly toward Jewishness but was not enough proof, then this may be considered a gerus l'chumra (a conversion done to resolve doubt, for a person who is likely already Jewish.)

Comment: It would seem that in many cases a chazaka would be in the mix.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes...

Rabbi Leib Tropper is maybe the rabbi most versed in complicated issues of conversion, and I have seen him deal personally with several people who were unsure if they were Jewish. This is what I understood from his response to the above questions:

- There **are** precedents, and the standard ruling is as follows:
- It **does** matter; even if a person is not sure he is Jewish he needs to follow the law.
- He **does** sin if he is Jewish and does not keep Mitzvos.
- He **should** convert.

Until he converts, he should make sure to do *melacha motzoei shabbes*. (Wearing tzitzis may not be enough if there is *eruv* or maybe even if there is no real *reshus harabim*.)

Comment: "maybe"??? Is that really even a possibility?

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe he meant "even if there is no eruv, if it isn't a real reshus harabim maybe it won't be enough to be considered melacha" i.e. maybe you need to do a melacha d'oraiysa.

Comment: @YEZ Wrong "maybe".

Comment: @DoubleAA Why not?